# Store user test results against their profile in Drupal Quiz Site

Tags: 7, database, entities, users

I have created a drupal quiz site without depending any quiz modules. I want the user to be able to save their Test result against their profile. So they can see when they log in.

The Result will be like this usually:

> **Total Result:** 24/30.
>   **Main Subject:** Main_Subject_Name.
>   **Sub-sub1 score:** 12/15.
>   **Sub-Sub2 score:** 12/15.

There can be any no. of sub-subjects depending on test. It would be great if I could be able to pull them later with views.

This is what i have in mind. Create a content type results with 2 fields.  User Id and Data.
User id will hold the uid and in data i will add a json(ified) version of the result for later use. Is this ok? or are there any drupal specific ways to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can also create fields directly attached to the User entity just as you would to a content type.  It may make more sense to store the information for a specific user in fields attached to their identity directly. You can create views and panels to display the information however you want and provide hook functions in a custom module to do whatever specialized calculations you desire for presenting averages, grades etc.

I also noticed that you have used the Profile tag which relates to a module that has been deprecated for D7.  If you have the module enabled, I recommend not using it for any future site since it will very likely not be maintained in D8.